# UITextView contentSize make no sense compare to its frame.size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm trying to dynamically change the textView font size to bigger/smaller (with no success...) to fit its frame.
Even when I set a huge font and clearly half of the text is out of sight (too big/too small), the `textView.contentSize` and `textView.frame.size` are equal.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)changeSizeForTextView:(UITextView*)textView
{
    if (textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height) {
        int fontIncrement = 1;

        while (textView.contentSize.height > textView.frame.size.height) {
            textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kFontName size:MAX_FONT_SIZE - fontIncrement];
            fontIncrement++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this method? Also, how do you add your `textView` to your view (programmatically vs IB/Storyboard)

Comment: Via storyboard, referencing the textView works but it doesn't enter the if.

Comment: Again, where are you calling this method? `viewDidLoad`? `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Via subclassed UIView

Comment: In order for the code you wrote to be executed, it needs to be *called* somewhere. I don't care where the code is housed. As this is not overriding a system method (like `init` or `viewDidAppear` or `copyWithZone`) that can be called automatically by the OS, you have to actually execute this code somehow by calling the method. Where is the call to this method? Is it in your view controller's `viewDidAppear`? Is it in a table view's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Where are you calling this method?

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

Answer (score 0):

OK, based on a few codes I gathered here here is the answer:

- First of all, 'Selectable' must be checked in storyboard (I disable it thru code later).

Usage:

```
[textView dynamicFontSize];
```

UITextView+Dynamic.h

```
//
//  UITextView+Dynamic.h
//  MyFinder
//
//  Created by admin on 9/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Webnet Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITextView (Dynamic)
- (BOOL)dynamicFontSize;
-(BOOL)sizeFontToFit:(NSString*)aString minSize:(float)aMinFontSize maxSize:(float)aMaxFontSize;
@end
```

UITextView+Dynamic.m

```
//
//  UITextView+Dynamic.m
//  MyFinder
//
//  Created by admin on 9/21/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Webnet Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UITextView+Dynamic.h"

#define kMaxFieldHeight 9999

static const CGFloat MAX_FONT_SIZE = 30.0;
static const CGFloat MIN_FONT_SIZE = 4.0;

@implementation UITextView (Dynamic)

- (BOOL)dynamicFontSize
{
    return [self sizeFontToFit:self.text minSize:MIN_FONT_SIZE maxSize:MAX_FONT_SIZE];
}

-(BOOL)sizeFontToFit:(NSString*)aString minSize:(float)aMinFontSize maxSize:(float)aMaxFontSize
{
    float fudgeFactor = 16.0;
    float fontSize = aMaxFontSize;

    self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];

    CGSize tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
    CGSize stringSize = [aString boundingRectWithSize:tallerSize
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.font}
                                              context:nil].size;

    while (stringSize.height >= self.frame.size.height)
    {
        if (fontSize <= aMinFontSize) // it just won't fit
            return NO;

        fontSize -= 1.0;
        self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize];
        tallerSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width-fudgeFactor,kMaxFieldHeight);
        stringSize = [aString boundingRectWithSize:tallerSize
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.font}
                                           context:nil].size;
    }

    self.font = [self.font fontWithSize:self.font.pointSize - 1.0];
    return YES;
}

@end
```